# Import data from web: repeat loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA script that works:

```
Sub Basic_Web_Query()

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, Destination:=Range("E2"))
.Name = "q?s=goog_2"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebTables = "2"
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

I want the macro to do this in a loop, i.e. go to A3 with destination E3, A4 with destination A4... etc.

any help will be appreciated

thansk!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `'offset'` for these loops:  `OFFSET(rows down, columns right)`. 
Negative values move up and left.

for example:

```
for p= 1 to 5

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").offset(p-1,0).Value, Destination:=Range("E2").offset(p-1,0))
'other code
End With

next p
```

Answer (score 0):

google 'loop vba' and you will hit plenty of examples. Here's one:

```
Dim rw As Long

For rw = 1 To 5
    Range("E" & rw).Value = Range("A" & rw).Value
    'other stuff
Next rw
```

Comment: I've just tried that but now i'm only getting the data imported for the last row, i.e. I put a range of 1 to 5 but I only have a return for line 5, the other 4 are blank. any tip? many thaks

Comment: General tip is to debug your code. Try to step over the code line by line (hitting F8) and check the values (by `Debug.Print` in the immediate window or by hovering your mouse over them). Start by the basic element of your code and add complexity step by step.